# GULP tap.js - cannot read property

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I've recently strated using GULP for building. But I've run into a wall, while attempting to run my "scripts" cleaning.

**the error**

```
D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src>gulp default
[23:13:03] Using gulpfile D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\gulpfile.js
[23:13:03] Starting 'lint:js'...
[23:13:03] Starting 'build:plugins'...
[23:13:03] Starting 'build:js'...
[23:13:03] Starting 'build:less'...
[23:13:03] Starting 'build:images'...
[23:13:03] Starting 'build:svgs'...
[23:13:03] Starting 'build:fonts'...
[23:13:03] Starting 'build:favicon'...
[23:13:03] Finished 'build:favicon' after 2.19 ms
[23:13:03] Finished 'build:plugins' after 78 ms
D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\gulp-tap\lib\tap.js:60
    if (obj instanceof baseStream && !obj._readableState.ended) {
                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ended' of undefined
    at DestroyableTransform.modifyFile (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\gulp-tap\lib\tap.js:60:57)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:182:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:170:83)
    at doWrite (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:406:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:395:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:322:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:612:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at addChunk (D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:284:12)

D:\GitHub\ASGARD\baseThemeV2\src>
```

**The Gulp "Command" I'm using is** 
I believe the error is ".pipe(tap(function (file, t) {" -- But I don't know how "not" to use this.

```
// Lint, minify, and concatenate scripts
gulp.task('build:js',  function() {
    var jsTasks = lazypipe()
        .pipe(header, banner.full, { package : package })
        .pipe(gulp.dest, paths.scripts.output)
        .pipe(rename, { suffix: '.min' })
        .pipe(uglify)
        .pipe(header, banner.min, { package : package })
        .pipe(gulp.dest, paths.scripts.output);

    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.input)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
            if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
                var name = file.relative + '.js';
                return gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
                    .pipe(concat(name))
                    .pipe(jsTasks());
            }
        }))
        .pipe(jsTasks());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
if (obj instanceof baseStream && !obj._readableState.ended) {
  obj.on('end', next);
  return obj.on('data', data = function() {
    obj.removeListener('end', next);
    obj.removeListener('data', data);
    return next();
  });
} else {
  return next();
}
```

There is no property `_readableState` in `obj` therefore when we try to read `ended` we get an error. With some little googling we are able to land a similar [issue discussed on github](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2368#issuecomment-72182834), that confirms that indeed `_readableState` is not a must in streams.

> Streams are not required to have a _readableState state property. They will get this if the implementation inherits from stream.Readable, but otherwise there is no such guarantee.

If we then head on [to the Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_types_of_streams) we discover that there are several types of streams:

> There are four fundamental stream types within Node.js:

- Readable - streams from which data can be read (for example fs.createReadStream()).
- Writable - streams to which data can be written (for example fs.createWriteStream()).
- Duplex - streams that are both Readable and Writable (for example net.Socket).
- Transform - Duplex streams that can modify or transform the data as it is written and read (for example zlib.createDeflate()).

Back to the code, `obj` is what you return in your callback:

```
obj = lambda(inst.file, utils(this, inst.file), inst);
```

Namely:

```
return gulp.src(file.path + '/*.js')
    .pipe(concat(name))
    .pipe(jsTasks());
```

Is it a stream, but not a readable stream? If so the code will fail.

Gulp uses Vinyl streams and you probably need to convert it to a "normal" stream. This [gulp plugin](https://github.com/kevva/vinyl-to-stream/blob/master/index.js) seems to do the job.

P.S. Also I suggest you have a look at the examples `tap` provides, are you sure you need to return a stream in your case?